# Is there a 'touch delegate' equivalent in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

An android view can have a touch delegate to increase the clickable area of an element, without increasing it's padding.  Is there something like that in jetpack compose? I can't find a modifier that will do it.

Answer (score 0):

Move state to parent

```
@Composable
fun ViewScreen() {
    var scale by remember { mutableStateOf(1f) }
    var offset by remember { mutableStateOf(Offset.Zero) }
    var rotation by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }

    Column(
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        modifier = Modifier
            // touch event
            .pointerInput(Unit) {
                detectTransformGestures(
                    onGesture = { _, pan, gestureZoom, gestureRotate ->
                        scale *= gestureZoom
                        offset = offset.plus(pan)
                        rotation += gestureRotate
                    }
                )
            }
            .fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        Cube(scale, offset, rotation)
    }
}

@Composable
fun Cube(scale: Float, offset: Offset, rotation: Float) {
    Box(
        Modifier
            .graphicsLayer(
                scaleX = scale,
                scaleY = scale,
                rotationZ = rotation,
                translationX = offset.x,
                translationY = offset.y
            )
            .background(Color.Blue)
            .size(256.dp)
    )
}
```

- [state-hoisting](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#state-hoisting)
- [gestures](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/gestures)

Answer (score 0):

This is implementation i build, i haven't countered any errors in calculations but if you do comment or hope it helps you build better one based on this answer.

1-) Create data classes to increase or decrease dp size of touch area

```
@Immutable
data class DelegateRect(
    val left: Dp = 0.dp,
    val top: Dp = 0.dp,
    val right: Dp = 0.dp,
    val bottom: Dp = 0.dp
) {
    companion object {
        val Zero = DelegateRect()
    }
}

@Immutable
data class RectF(
    val left: Float = 0f,
    val top: Float = 0f,
    val right: Float = 0f,
    val bottom: Float = 0f
)
```

2-) Create a composed Modifier to restore or remember its state

```
fun Modifier.touchDelegate(
    dpRect: DelegateRect = DelegateRect.Zero,
    onClick: () -> Unit
) =
    composed(
    inspectorInfo = {
        name = "touchDelegate"
        properties["dpRect"] = dpRect
        properties["onClick"] = onClick
    },
        factory = {

            val density = LocalDensity.current

            var initialSize by remember {
                mutableStateOf(IntSize.Zero)
            }

            val updatedRect = remember(dpRect) {
                with(density) {
                    RectF(
                        left = dpRect.left.toPx(),
                        top = dpRect.top.toPx(),
                        right = dpRect.right.toPx(),
                        bottom = dpRect.bottom.toPx(),
                    )
                }
            }


            val scale = remember(initialSize, updatedRect) {
                getScale(initialSize, updatedRect)
            }


            Modifier
                .graphicsLayer {
                    scaleX = scale.x
                    scaleY = scale.y
                    this.translationX = -updatedRect.left
                    this.translationY = -updatedRect.top

                    transformOrigin = TransformOrigin(0f, 0f)
                }
                .clickable {
                    onClick()
                }
                .graphicsLayer {
                    val scaleX = if (scale.x == 0f) 1f else 1 / scale.x
                    val scaleY = if (scale.y == 0f) 1f else 1 / scale.y
                    this.scaleX = scaleX
                    this.scaleY = scaleY
                    this.translationX = (updatedRect.left) * scaleX
                    this.translationY = (updatedRect.top) * scaleY
                    transformOrigin = TransformOrigin(0f, 0f)
                }
                .onSizeChanged {
                    initialSize = it
                }
        }
    )
```

Let me explain step by step

3-) `Modifier.graphicsLayer{}` can scale, translate or rotate our Composable's layer. And order of it matters, if we set it before Modifier.clickable it increases both clickable area and Composable scale. Responsibility of `Modifier.graphicsLayer{}` on top is to scale up touch area and Composable, to scale and translate back to original position second `Modifier.graphicsLayer{}` is required.

4-) Basically we scale as new added dp size and translate left and top because our transform origin, normally it's center but more difficult to calculate translations.

5-) When translating back we need to consider reverse of scale.

6-) To have accurate scaling we need size of our Composable which we get from `Modifier.onSizeChanged{}`

7-) Scale function that creates scale using initial non zero size and the size after we add touch offset via rectangle

```
private fun getScale(initialSize: IntSize, updatedRect: RectF): Offset =
    if (initialSize.width == 0 ||
        initialSize.height == 0
    ) {
        Offset(1f, 1f)
    } else {
        val initialWidth = initialSize.width
        val initialHeight = initialSize.height
        val scaleX =
            ((updatedRect.left + updatedRect.right + initialWidth) / initialWidth)
                .coerceAtLeast(0f)
        val scaleY =
            ((updatedRect.top + updatedRect.bottom + initialHeight) / initialHeight)
                .coerceAtLeast(0f)
        Offset(scaleX, scaleY)
    }
```

Usage

```
Column(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
) {

    Image(
        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.landscape1),
        contentDescription = null,
        contentScale = ContentScale.FillBounds,
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(200.dp)
            .clickable { }
    )

    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(40.dp))

    Image(
        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.landscape1),
        contentDescription = null,
        contentScale = ContentScale.FillBounds,
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(200.dp)
            .touchDelegate(
                DelegateRect(
                    left = 50.dp,
                    top = 40.dp,
                    right = 70.dp,
                    bottom = 90.dp
                )
            ) {

            }
    )
}
```

Result

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I noticed when using this code, the actual click area is bigger than the overlay which appears which is not ideal. Any idea why?

Comment: After testing, I realized that the "minimumTouchTargetSize" in ViewConfiguration was expanding the clickable area beyond the bounds. 

Using a CompositionLocal to set it to zero fixes the issue. Not the ideal fix, but works well enough for me!

Answer (score -1):

I was looking for a cleaner solution for this and stumbled upon [ViewConfiguration](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/platform/ViewConfiguration) class. So basically clickable modifier relies upon `LocalViewConfiguration.current` to provide a default implementation. If you already know the size you want increase the touch area to, you can just provide a custom implementation of this class and override `minimumTouchTargetSize` to provide an updated size. Here is an example sublcass of View Configuration

```
class CustomViewConfiguration(
    private val viewConfiguration: android.view.ViewConfiguration,
    private val size: Dp
) : ViewConfiguration {
    override val longPressTimeoutMillis: Long
        get() = 
    android.view.ViewConfiguration.getLongPressTimeout().toLong()

    override val doubleTapTimeoutMillis: Long
        get() = 
    android.view.ViewConfiguration.getDoubleTapTimeout().toLong()

    override val doubleTapMinTimeMillis: Long
        get() = 40

    override val touchSlop: Float
        get() = viewConfiguration.scaledTouchSlop.toFloat()

    override val minimumTouchTargetSize: DpSize
        get() = DpSize(size, size)
}
```

Once this is defined, you can provide this to your composable by using `CompositionLocalProider`

```
CompositionLocalProvider(
    LocalViewConfiguration provides CustomViewConfiguration(
        android.view.ViewConfiguration.get(
            LocalContext.current
        ),
        size.dp
    )
) {
    // Your composable here that needs an increased size

}
```

If you don't know the increased size before hand, you can use `BoxWithConstraints` or any other `SubComposeLayout` which measures the composables and provides them in the constraints for you to use.

Comment: This does increase the touch size, but it doesn't expand the clickable highlight area.

Comment: To expand the highlight area I use canvas to draw custom highlight